# sort specific index in array in descending order

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

I have an array called look. It contains 10 items in it.
How do i sort index 7 to 9 in the array in descending order? 
below is code i use sort index 0 to 6 in ascending.

```
Arrays.sort(look, 0, 6);
```

Comment: So coming to arrays, have you check on any sorting methods?

Comment: yeah. i saw collections.reverseorder. but it seems it doesn't allow to specify the index number to sort.

Comment: Thanks. I changed my look from int to Integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Arrays.sort(look, 7, 9, Collections.reverseOrder());`

should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Arrays method:

`public static <T> void sort(T[] a, int fromIndex, int toIndex, Comparator<? super T> c)`

With help of the Comparator interface you can define you own sorting mechanism.

see: [public static  void sort(T[] a, int fromIndex, int toIndex, Comparator c))](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5b%5d,%20int,%20int,%20java.util.Comparator%29) and [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)